# I'm trying to make an email verification system by I keep getting an error "Undefined variable: code"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm making a verification system using laravel8. The system works fine and it allows a user (me) to register. After registration, an email is sent to the user with a verification link. Now, the problem occurs when the user clicks the link. An error "Undefined variable: code". Here's the error and the code [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gu8x2.png)

ActivateAccountController
<?php

```
  namespace App\Http\Controllers;
  use App\Models\User;
  use Illuminate\Http\Request;
  use App\Mail\ActivateYourAccount;
  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

  class ActivateAccountController extends Controller
 {
//
public function activation(){
    $user = User::where('code',$code)->first();
    $user->code = null;
    $user->update([
        'active' => 1
    ]);
    auth()->login($user);
    return redirect('/')->withSuccess('Connected');
    }

    public function resendCode($email){
    $user = User::where('email',$email)->first();
    if($user->active){
        return redirect('/');
    }
    Mail::to($user)->send(new ActivateYourAccount($user->code));
    return redirect('/login')->withSuccess('The link was sent to your email address');
   }
   }
```

Can anyone assist me with a solution to the problem which appears on line13

```
$user = User::where('code',$code)->first();
```

Comment: can you show route for tht url and error is activation($code).you havent passed param in method

Comment: This is the first line of `activation()`: `$user = User::where('code',$code)->first();`... You don't define `$code` anywhere before that. Is there something unclear about your error message?

Comment: Thank you @TimLewis. Your solution fixed my problem